# Does Ubuntu 22.04 offer a recent version of Maven

Tags: maven, ubuntu

I just upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 22.04 and when I run mvn --version is still see:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.15, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.0-1013-aws", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

which is almost a 2 years old version.

I would like to avoid a manual install and keep using apt to manage the installation of maven. Am I asking for too much or did I miss something?

Comment: Download it manually it's easier: https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Answer (score 0):

Running Ubuntu 22.10:

```
mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 17.0.4, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.19.0-15-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```